# Migration: If entity lookup fails to find a matching term then the entire row should fail

Tags: drupal-8

I have a list of terms for a vocab which I need to import. However the 
original term data is not sanitized. So we want to only import if entity lookup finds the term in drupal.

If the term is not found in drupal then the row should fail during migration.

I coded the below but it does not seem to work. Am I using the wrong plugin
`skip_on_emtpy` ?

```
field_initiative:
  -
    source: original_source_data
    plugin: entity_lookup
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: initiative
    value_key: name
    ignore_case: true
  -
    plugin: skip_on_empty
    method: row
    message: 'Skipped Missing Term Initiative'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create migration plugin and return true or false. Check this module [Migrate Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) and find its examples to learn how to create migration process plugin. But the easiest and shortest way would be to cleanup the migration source data and run migration.